# Filter date column in React table

Tags: reactjs, react-table

How can i filter a date column (date format is dd.mm.yyy) in react table ?
I searched quite a bit, but could not find any solution.
Any thoughts ?

```
Header: 'header'
accessor: 'accessor',
filterMethod: --> need to fill here
```

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own filter format like *.08.* ans split filter text by `.` and check if each parts of date ( day, month ,year) match with it

Comment: thanks, did something like this: filterMethod: (filter, row) => {
                                                    const rowValue = row._original
                                                    return rowValue.datefiled.includes(filter.value)
                                                },

Comment: Yeah it's good but if you want more efficient filter use format like i suggest you to avoid bad filtering


For example with your method filter with 05, give you the 5th month and the 5th day